# csv header row as array key

Tags: php, arrays, csv, curl

I'm able to get the file into an array, but I'd like to get the key's to be the first row.  Here's is the curl command:

```
 $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url.com/download");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$headers[] = "X-App-Key: xxxxx";
$headers[] = "X-User-Key: yyyy";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);


$data = array_map("str_getcsv", preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $result));

return $data;
```

Here is the csv that is returned:

```
"Date,Campaign,Campaign Id,Impressions,Clicks,CTR,Platform Cost,Search Cost,Demographic Cost,Contextual Cost,Behavioral Cost,Geographic Cost,Segment Cost,Media Cost,CPM,Total Spend,ECPC,Click Sales,Click Leads,Click Signups,Click Other,View Sales,View Leads,View Signups,View Other,CPA,Weighted Actions 2017-05-16,Company,326606,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,,2.00 2017-05-18,Company,326606,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,,2.00 2017-05-19,Company,326606,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,,2.00 2017-05-20,Company,326606,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,,2.00 2017-05-28,Company,326606,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,,1.00 2017-06-02,Company,326606,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,,1.00 2017-05-10,Company,326606,16877,41,0.002429,0.770373,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.770373,0.000000,1.540785,3.081682,52.009548,1.268526,,,,,,,,,, 2017-05-11,Company,326606,17001,50,0.002941,0.764775,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.764775,0.000000,1.529592,3.059288,52.010956,1.040219,,,,,,,,,, 2017-05-12,Company,326606,16814,44,0.002617,0.773364,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.773364,0.000000,1.546763,3.093651,52.016652,1.182197,,,,,,,,,, 2017-05-13,Company,326606,16880,32,0.001896,0.770245,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.770245,0.000000,1.540520,3.081195,52.010570,1.625330,,,,,,,,,, 2017-05-14,Company,326606,17045,32,0.001877,0.762742,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.762742,0.000000,1.525543,3.051212,52.007907,1.625247,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,52.0079,1.00 2017-05-15,Company,326606,7294,10,0.001371,0.781126,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.781126,0.000000,1.562252,3.124683,22.791441,2.279144,,,,,,,,,, 2017-06-03,Company,559435,30186,42,0.001391,0.690422,0.690422,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.000000,1.380910,2.761773,83.366884,1.984926,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,41.6834,2.00 2017-06-04,Company,559435,29952,25,0.000835,0.695962,0.695962,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.000000,1.391983,2.783917,83.383894,3.335356,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,6.9487,12.00 2017-06-05,Company,559435,29863,39,0.001306,0.697854,0.697854,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.000000,1.395772,2.791494,83.362371,2.137497,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,15,3.7892,22.00 2017-06-06,Company,559435,29859,40,0.001340,0.698055,0.698055,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.000000,1.396160,2.792283,83.374777,2.084369,0,1,0,4,2,1,0,21,2.8750,29.00 2017-06-07,Company,559435,29968,22,0.000734,0.695653,0.695653,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.000000,1.391359,2.782683,83.391458,3.790521,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,25,3.2074,26.00 2017-06-08,Company,559435,29967,41,0.001368,0.695284,0.695284,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.000000,1.390634,2.781195,83.344075,2.032782,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,23,3.2055,26.00 2017-06-09,Company,559435,14689,8,0.000545,0.686755,0.686755,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.000000,0.000000,1.373565,2.747041,40.351291,5.043911,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,21,1.7544,23.00 ,,,286395,426,0.001487,0.718754,0.471867,0.0,0.000000,0.0,0.246886,0.000000,1.437560,2.875126,823.421824,1.932915,0,1,0,12,5,4,0,129,5.4531,151.00
```

And the returned array is but I'd like "date" "clicks" to be used as the keys so I can simply call "$data[Click Lead]":

```
array(22) {
  [0]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Date"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "Campaign"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "Campaign Id"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "Impressions"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "Clicks"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "CTR"
    [6]=>
    string(13) "Platform Cost"
    [7]=>
    string(11) "Search Cost"
    [8]=>
    string(16) "Demographic Cost"
    [9]=>
    string(15) "Contextual Cost"
    [10]=>
    string(15) "Behavioral Cost"
    [11]=>
    string(15) "Geographic Cost"
    [12]=>
    string(12) "Segment Cost"
    [13]=>
    string(10) "Media Cost"
    [14]=>
    string(3) "CPM"
    [15]=>
    string(11) "Total Spend"
    [16]=>
    string(4) "ECPC"
    [17]=>
    string(11) "Click Sales"
    [18]=>
    string(11) "Click Leads"
    [19]=>
    string(13) "Click Signups"
    [20]=>
    string(11) "Click Other"
    [21]=>
    string(10) "View Sales"
    [22]=>
    string(10) "View Leads"
    [23]=>
    string(12) "View Signups"
    [24]=>
    string(10) "View Other"
    [25]=>
    string(3) "CPA"
    [26]=>
    string(16) "Weighted Actions"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-16"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(0) ""
    [6]=>
    string(0) ""
    [7]=>
    string(0) ""
    [8]=>
    string(0) ""
    [9]=>
    string(0) ""
    [10]=>
    string(0) ""
    [11]=>
    string(0) ""
    [12]=>
    string(0) ""
    [13]=>
    string(0) ""
    [14]=>
    string(0) ""
    [15]=>
    string(0) ""
    [16]=>
    string(0) ""
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(4) "2.00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-18"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(0) ""
    [6]=>
    string(0) ""
    [7]=>
    string(0) ""
    [8]=>
    string(0) ""
    [9]=>
    string(0) ""
    [10]=>
    string(0) ""
    [11]=>
    string(0) ""
    [12]=>
    string(0) ""
    [13]=>
    string(0) ""
    [14]=>
    string(0) ""
    [15]=>
    string(0) ""
    [16]=>
    string(0) ""
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(4) "2.00"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-19"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(0) ""
    [6]=>
    string(0) ""
    [7]=>
    string(0) ""
    [8]=>
    string(0) ""
    [9]=>
    string(0) ""
    [10]=>
    string(0) ""
    [11]=>
    string(0) ""
    [12]=>
    string(0) ""
    [13]=>
    string(0) ""
    [14]=>
    string(0) ""
    [15]=>
    string(0) ""
    [16]=>
    string(0) ""
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(4) "2.00"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-20"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(0) ""
    [6]=>
    string(0) ""
    [7]=>
    string(0) ""
    [8]=>
    string(0) ""
    [9]=>
    string(0) ""
    [10]=>
    string(0) ""
    [11]=>
    string(0) ""
    [12]=>
    string(0) ""
    [13]=>
    string(0) ""
    [14]=>
    string(0) ""
    [15]=>
    string(0) ""
    [16]=>
    string(0) ""
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(4) "2.00"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-28"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(0) ""
    [6]=>
    string(0) ""
    [7]=>
    string(0) ""
    [8]=>
    string(0) ""
    [9]=>
    string(0) ""
    [10]=>
    string(0) ""
    [11]=>
    string(0) ""
    [12]=>
    string(0) ""
    [13]=>
    string(0) ""
    [14]=>
    string(0) ""
    [15]=>
    string(0) ""
    [16]=>
    string(0) ""
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(4) "1.00"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-06-02"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(0) ""
    [6]=>
    string(0) ""
    [7]=>
    string(0) ""
    [8]=>
    string(0) ""
    [9]=>
    string(0) ""
    [10]=>
    string(0) ""
    [11]=>
    string(0) ""
    [12]=>
    string(0) ""
    [13]=>
    string(0) ""
    [14]=>
    string(0) ""
    [15]=>
    string(0) ""
    [16]=>
    string(0) ""
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(4) "1.00"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-10"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "16877"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "41"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.002429"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.770373"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.770373"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.540785"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "3.081682"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "52.009548"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "1.268526"
    [17]=>
    string(0) ""
    [18]=>
    string(0) ""
    [19]=>
    string(0) ""
    [20]=>
    string(0) ""
    [21]=>
    string(0) ""
    [22]=>
    string(0) ""
    [23]=>
    string(0) ""
    [24]=>
    string(0) ""
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [8]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-11"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "17001"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "50"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.002941"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.764775"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.764775"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.529592"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "3.059288"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "52.010956"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "1.040219"
    [17]=>
    string(0) ""
    [18]=>
    string(0) ""
    [19]=>
    string(0) ""
    [20]=>
    string(0) ""
    [21]=>
    string(0) ""
    [22]=>
    string(0) ""
    [23]=>
    string(0) ""
    [24]=>
    string(0) ""
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [9]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-12"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "16814"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "44"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.002617"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.773364"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.773364"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.546763"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "3.093651"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "52.016652"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "1.182197"
    [17]=>
    string(0) ""
    [18]=>
    string(0) ""
    [19]=>
    string(0) ""
    [20]=>
    string(0) ""
    [21]=>
    string(0) ""
    [22]=>
    string(0) ""
    [23]=>
    string(0) ""
    [24]=>
    string(0) ""
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [10]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-13"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "16880"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "32"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.001896"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.770245"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.770245"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.540520"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "3.081195"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "52.010570"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "1.625330"
    [17]=>
    string(0) ""
    [18]=>
    string(0) ""
    [19]=>
    string(0) ""
    [20]=>
    string(0) ""
    [21]=>
    string(0) ""
    [22]=>
    string(0) ""
    [23]=>
    string(0) ""
    [24]=>
    string(0) ""
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [11]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-14"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "17045"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "32"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.001877"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.762742"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.762742"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.525543"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "3.051212"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "52.007907"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "1.625247"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [25]=>
    string(7) "52.0079"
    [26]=>
    string(4) "1.00"
  }
  [12]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-15"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "326606"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "7294"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.001371"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.781126"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.781126"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.562252"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "3.124683"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "22.791441"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "2.279144"
    [17]=>
    string(0) ""
    [18]=>
    string(0) ""
    [19]=>
    string(0) ""
    [20]=>
    string(0) ""
    [21]=>
    string(0) ""
    [22]=>
    string(0) ""
    [23]=>
    string(0) ""
    [24]=>
    string(0) ""
    [25]=>
    string(0) ""
    [26]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [13]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-06-03"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "559435"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "30186"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "42"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.001391"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.690422"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.690422"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.380910"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "2.761773"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "83.366884"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "1.984926"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [25]=>
    string(7) "41.6834"
    [26]=>
    string(4) "2.00"
  }
  [14]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-06-04"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "559435"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "29952"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "25"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.000835"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.695962"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.695962"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.391983"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "2.783917"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "83.383894"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "3.335356"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [25]=>
    string(6) "6.9487"
    [26]=>
    string(5) "12.00"
  }
  [15]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-06-05"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "559435"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "29863"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "39"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.001306"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.697854"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.697854"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.395772"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "2.791494"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "83.362371"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "2.137497"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(2) "15"
    [25]=>
    string(6) "3.7892"
    [26]=>
    string(5) "22.00"
  }
  [16]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-06-06"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "559435"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "29859"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "40"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.001340"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.698055"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.698055"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.396160"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "2.792283"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "83.374777"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "2.084369"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(2) "21"
    [25]=>
    string(6) "2.8750"
    [26]=>
    string(5) "29.00"
  }
  [17]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-06-07"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "559435"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "29968"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "22"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.000734"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.695653"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.695653"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.391359"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "2.782683"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "83.391458"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "3.790521"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(2) "25"
    [25]=>
    string(6) "3.2074"
    [26]=>
    string(5) "26.00"
  }
  [18]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-06-08"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "559435"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "29967"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "41"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.001368"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.695284"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.695284"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.390634"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "2.781195"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "83.344075"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "2.032782"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(2) "23"
    [25]=>
    string(6) "3.2055"
    [26]=>
    string(5) "26.00"
  }
  [19]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2017-06-09"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "Company"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "559435"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "14689"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "8"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.000545"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.686755"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.686755"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.373565"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "2.747041"
    [15]=>
    string(9) "40.351291"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "5.043911"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(2) "21"
    [25]=>
    string(6) "1.7544"
    [26]=>
    string(5) "23.00"
  }
  [20]=>
  array(27) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    [3]=>
    string(6) "286395"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "426"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "0.001487"
    [6]=>
    string(8) "0.718754"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "0.471867"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [9]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [10]=>
    string(3) "0.0"
    [11]=>
    string(8) "0.246886"
    [12]=>
    string(8) "0.000000"
    [13]=>
    string(8) "1.437560"
    [14]=>
    string(8) "2.875126"
    [15]=>
    string(10) "823.421824"
    [16]=>
    string(8) "1.932915"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [18]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [20]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [22]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [23]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [24]=>
    string(3) "129"
    [25]=>
    string(6) "5.4531"
    [26]=>
    string(6) "151.00"
  }
  [21]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to iterate through and create a copy of the array, adding the values of the first iteration as keys yourself.  What have you tried, so far?

Comment: Can't you just do `$data = json_decode( $result, true );`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a one line solution, but it will be easiest if you remove the superfluous curl connection to get the csv (that is not relevant to your question, you see), and instead, provide the first few rows of the csv for use in returning you an potential solution. Or as @alon-eitan causes me to realize, providing a sample json would work, too.

Comment: @AlonEitan When I do the json_decode I get "NULL" that was the first thing I tried.

Comment: @WEBjuju . I've added the CSV, I've left the curl since it's what I was using to create the array. It has been ages since I coded so all help is appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) and extend your code to:

```
$data = array_map("str_getcsv", preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $result));

$new_data = [];

// shift first element of $data, we will use it as keys.
$keys = array_shift($data);
foreach ($data as $item) {
    // create key => value array
    $new_data[] = array_combine($keys, $item);
}
```

Thanks to @Kazz - in case of warnings like

> array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

you need to check if both elements are arrays and theirs sizes equals (with `count()`, for example).

Comment: Thanks, at first blush I'm getting: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements.

Comment: @Dan because of last line in csv: `[21] => array(1) { [0]=> NULL }`